# How to Store and Read Map[String, String] in Hive, Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I am trying to store http headers in `Map[String, String]` and read in Spark program
created hive table and insert records into table

```
create table test_map2(
col1 Map<String, String>);

insert into test_map2
select       Map('Id', 'aaabbbccc',
        'Accept', 'app/json',
        'Accept-Encoding', 'app/gzip');
```

in Spark, I am not able to extract data in `Map[String, String]`
so I tried in this way

1. from hive extract data in `String`
2. convert `String` to `Array[String]`
3. convert `Array[String]` to `Map[String, String]`

```scala
val a = hive.table("test_map2").rdd.map(x => x.toString.drop(2).dropRight(2)).collect().take(1)(0).toString

val inArray = a.split(",")

var headerMap = Map.empty[String, String]
    
inArray.foreach(arg => {
   val keyVal = arg.split(":")
    headerMap = headerMap + (keyVal(0) -> keyVal(1))
 })
```

Now I am able to convert the data to map type but I use this `Map` in http request it is not working

```scala
Http(httpsRequestString)
      .headers(headerMap)
      .postData(postData)
      .asString
```

I am looking for

1. is there a simple way to extract data in `Map[String, String]` from Hive table
2. is there a other way to make http request (using headers data from hive table)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a map, how about a table with two columns, header and value?